# Не могу понять в чём проблема почему anaconda не может подтянуть seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda, seaborn

Пытаюсь импортировать библиотеки :

1. import pandas as pd
2. import seaborn as sns
3. import rcParams

```html
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division,
                        print_function, unicode_literals)
    # отключим предупреждения Anaconda
    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')

    # будем отображать графики прямо в jupyter'e
    %pylab inline
   #графики в svg выглядят более четкими
    %config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg' 

   #увеличим дефолтный размер графиков
    from pylab import rcParams
    rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 6,3
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns
```

Но выдаёт ошибку :

```html
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-a00b5071d104> in <module>
     16 rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 6,3
     17 import pandas as pd
---> 18 import seaborn as sns

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # Import seaborn objects
----> 6 from .rcmod import *
      7 from .utils import *
      8 from .palettes import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py in <module>
      3 import functools
      4 import matplotlib as mpl
----> 5 from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
      6 
      7 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py in <module>
     10 from .external.six.moves import range
     11 
---> 12 from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
     13 from .colors import xkcd_rgb, crayons
     14 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py in <module>
      5 
      6 import numpy as np
----> 7 from scipy import stats
      8 import pandas as pd
      9 import matplotlib as mpl

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>
    365 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    366 
--> 367 from .stats import *
    368 from .distributions import *
    369 from .morestats import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>
    171 from scipy._lib._util import _lazywhere
    172 import scipy.special as special
--> 173 from . import distributions
    174 from . import mstats_basic
    175 from ._stats_mstats_common import _find_repeats, linregress, theilslopes, siegelslopes

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py in <module>
      8 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
      9 
---> 10 from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
     11                                     rv_frozen)
     12 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in <module>
     14 import warnings
     15 
---> 16 from scipy.misc import doccer
     17 from ._distr_params import distcont, distdiscrete
     18 from scipy._lib._util import check_random_state

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py in <module>
     66 from numpy import who as _who, source as _source, info as _info
     67 import numpy as np
---> 68 from scipy.interpolate._pade import pade as _pade
     69 from scipy.special import (comb as _comb, logsumexp as _lsm,
     70         factorial as _fact, factorial2 as _fact2, factorialk as _factk)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py in <module>
    173 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    174 
--> 175 from .interpolate import *
    176 from .fitpack import *
    177 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py in <module>
     30 from . import _ppoly
     31 from .fitpack2 import RectBivariateSpline
---> 32 from .interpnd import _ndim_coords_from_arrays
     33 from ._bsplines import make_interp_spline, BSpline
     34 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpnd.cp37-win_amd64.pyd in init scipy.interpolate.interpnd()

AttributeError: type object 'scipy.interpolate.interpnd.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

Comment: Причём сейчас сделал  тест : Создал другой файл и скопировал этот код в новый файл и ошибку не выдал и всё подключил без проблем.

Comment: Какие у вас версии scipy и cython?

Comment: Python - 3.7 Версия 
Scipy - 1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать новое виртуальное окружение при помощи `conda`.

Сначала лучше обновить сам `conda` менеджер.

Запустите `Anaconda Prompt`. Все последующие команды запускаются из `Anaconda Prompt`:

```
conda update conda
# создаем новое виртуальное окружение `ml` (Machine Learning)
conda create -n ml python=3.7 anaconda pandas ipython jupyter seaborn
```

Далее запускайте `Jupyer Notebook` из созданного виртуального окружения:

```
C:\Users\<user-name>\Anaconda3\envs\ml\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe
#  ------------------------->  ^^^^^^^
```

---

**NOTE:** если создать новое окружение *чисто*, используя только менеджер `conda`, то `conda` сама подберёт все *совместимые* версии модулей. Это минимизирует вероятность возникновения подобных ошибок. Кроме того вы получите независимое окружение, которое можно изменять/обновлять/удалять/пересоздавать независимо от базового и других окружений (`VirtualEnv`).

PS [официальная документация по `conda`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)